# Compile-time assert when not all enum values are handled in a switch statement in C++

Tags: c++

I'd like to get a compiler warning or error when not all possible enum values are handled in a switch statement. Of course I can add a default case with an assert and (eventually) get an error at runtime. But I'd like to get an error at compile-time.

I'm not sure if this is possible at all with C++, but maybe someone knows a trick...

Edit:
Using `-Wswitch` seems to be the solution for GCC. Is there something similar for VS2010? (I'm not using GCC).

Edit2:
Ok, I found the solution for VC++ (VS2010):

Enabling warning `C4062` produces a warning when a value is missing und no default case is provided.

Enabling warning `C4061` produces a warning when a value is missing, even if a default case is provided.

Answer (score 8):

You haven't mentioned which compiler you're using.  If you're using GCC, you can get that for free simply by enabling `-Wswitch` (which is automatically enabled by `-Wall`).

Answer (score 6):

### Been trying to solve a similair problem, Id like to elaborate on the answers above

Previous answers by:

- Oliver Charlesworth
- BЈовић
- TonyK

(9 years late, Sorry | Maybe I'll help someone in the future)

---

If you have a switch statement like such:

```
switch (EnumClass){
   case EnumA: do_something();   return;
   case EnumB: do_other_thing(); return;
   .
   .
   case EnumZ: last_do_thing();  return;
}
```

GCC can be your greatest friend and can catch these issues for you when something is changed in the enumerator.

The key here is the **[Compile-Time warning-options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)**, specifically the:

- `-Wswitch` (Warns for un-handled Enum values *IF* there isnt a `default` in the switch)
- `-Wswitch-default` (Warns if there isnt a `default` in a switch statement)
- `-Wswitch-enum` (Same as `-Wswitch`, but warns even if there is a `default` in the switch)

As Mentioned above, the `-Wall` option includes the `-Wswitch` option, but not the other 2, so those have to be individual

---

Now, these arent very useful if somebody else modifies your code and compiles it *without* the flag... **SO**

*You may want to use `#pragma` statements to force the check.*

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wswitch"

enum EnumClass{
   EnumA,
   EnumB,
   .
   .
   EnumZ,
}

EnumClass EnumVal = EnumA;

switch (EnumVal){
   case EnumA: //Something
   case EnumB: //Other Thing
   .
   .
   case EnumZ: //Final Thing
}

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

What do these pragma statments mean? Good question! [reference for below info](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html)

`#pragma GCC diagnostic push`

This statement tells GCC to take note of the existing warning configuration (either set by the command line call to GCC, or by other #pragma statements earlier in the code)

`#pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wswitch"`

This statement tells GCC to throw a compile Error whenever a -Wswitch violation is found. (overrides the command line option and previous #pragma)

`#pragma GCC diagnostic pop`

This statement restores the compile settings to the most recent `push`, in this case, the one we did earlier.

These #pragma statements are useful for all sorts of stuff, with limitations loosely noted in the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.3/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#Diagnostic-Pragmas)

---

### In Summary

Use `-Wswitch` or `-Wall` in the command line to check to make sure enums are all handled (or default exists to handle them). Or use `-Wswitch-enum` to check for all enums regardless of default statement.

If you want GCC to check without having to use the flag manually, use `#pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wswitch"` or `#pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wswitch-enum"`

**Good Luck!**

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK there's no conventional way to achieve what you want with MSVC. There're tricks to do similar things, but they involve either a sophisticated template voodoo, or really fierce macros riddles.

For example, instead of defining your enum in a conventional way do the following:

```
#define MyEnumEntries(m) \
    m(A, 1) \
    m(B, 2) \
    m(C, 3) \

enum Abc {

    // the following will expand into your enum values definitions
#   define M_Decl(name, value) name = value,
    MyEnumEntries(M_Decl)
};
```

Now, your switch can be rewritten into this:

```
Abc a = A;

switch( a )
{
#define M_Goto(name, value) \
case value:
    goto label_##name;

MyEnumEntries(M_Goto)


case label_A:
    // TODO
    break;
case label_B:
    // TODO
    break;
}
```

The above will not compile if you won't add the switch entry `label_...` for all the enum values.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using g++, with `-Wall`, then you will get it.

For example, this :

```
enum Abc
{
  A =1,
  B,
  C
};

Abc a = A;
switch( a )
{
 case A:
  break;
 case B:
  break;
}
```

is going to cause a warning.

But it is better to use `default` case with failed assertion, because when you add a new enum value, you have to change all the files where you are using switch on this enum.

Comment: That sounds like a reason *not* to use `default`!  Surely you want the compiler to help you locate `enum` locations, rather than mask the problem?

Comment: @Oli That depends on your preferences. If you like compiler warnings, then adding one enum forces you to change all switches. If you prefere run-time warning, then you can concentrate on small pieces of code (divide and conquer).

Comment: @VJo: You should **always** prefer compiler warnings (as errors, ideally) where they are available.  Relying on run-time warnings means that you cannot be sure everything's fixed until you've run every possible code path with every possible input combination; that's ludicrous if the compiler will trivially spot this for you!

Comment: @Oli The problem with that is this **forces** you to implement those missing switches. But I guess you are right.

Comment: @VJO: Yes, in this case, it does force you.  But what's the alternative?  Either you need special handling for the new cases, or you don't (in which case you should use a `default`).

Comment: @Oli The alternative is with default :) If you use a feature which depends on new enum, the operation should fail with appropriate message (log or screen). This allows to divide the problem (if you got several places which you need to change, and possible assign more people.

Answer (score 1):

g++ does this automatically if you enable all warnings with `-Wall`.