# Is there a good way to ensure that specific switch statement handles all enum values?

Tags: c++, enums, switch-statement

I have an enum

```cpp
enum class Colors {
    RED,
    GREEN,
    BLUE
}
```

and a switch statement:

```cpp
switch (Colors) {
    case Colors::RED:
        //do something
        break;
    case Colors::GREEN:
        //do something
        break;
    case Colors::BLUE:
        //do something
        break;
}
```

Is there a good way to ensure that this switch statement always has the same amount of nodes as number of values in 'Colors' and throw an error at compile time if not?
I need this to work only on this specific switch statement, not other switch statements.

EDIT:
for `MSVC` this works:

```cpp
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning (default: 4062)
#pragma warning (error: 4062)
function_to_which_the_warning_is_applied() {}
#pragma warning(pop)
```

Comment: `gcc` has `-Wswitch-enum` warning, you can make it into an error.

Comment: @KamilCuk Why not adding this as the answer? That's exactly what I would do and it solves this problem perfectly

Comment: Well, will do. Not adding because it's not a portable solution.

Comment: @KamilCuk I am using MSVC, but your answer directed me in the right direction. If you post it as an answer I will accept it, thanks.

Comment: For options with both gcc and VC++ (VS2010) have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094141/compile-time-assert-when-not-all-enum-values-are-handled-in-a-switch-statement-i

Comment: Some compilers have warning switches, as mentioned.  If you are looking for a purely C++ solution, alas, as far as I am aware C++ itself provides no mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically configure compiler options in desired way.

The simplest choice (which will cover other common mistakes) is to use `-Wall -Werror` for gcc or clang and `/W4 /WX` for msvc (`/W4` do not cover respective warning so `/we4062` is needed, `/WX /Wall` detects [to much issues](https://godbolt.org/z/M77e6n) from standard header files).
https://godbolt.org/z/3sEvnP

You can also configure single warning: `-Wswitch-enum` `/we4062`.
https://godbolt.org/z/f1ox8E